# Switching between file paths in Java

Tags: java, filestream, mergesort, external-sorting

I am writing a mergesort for an externalsort, which reads 2 chunks of data at a time from a file A, merges them into a larger chunk, and writes it to a file B. After this, I need to then read 2 of these increased chunks at a time from file B, merge them into 1 larger chunk, and write this to file A. This switching goes on until all the data counts as 1 chunk at the end.

I have tried swapping the identifiers around like this after each iteration:

```
RandomAccessFile temp = fileA;
    fileA = fileB;
    fileB = temp;
```

This requires, that I update the BufferedInput and BufferedOutputStreams with the new file directory names and construct them each time.

I have a limited amount of RAM, so I cannot keep creating new objects unless I have to. Is there a better way to switch the target file and source file each iteration?

Comment: Does this way not work?  What is your measure for "better"?

Comment: Are you using Threads ?

Comment: It does work, but I need to run the stream constructors every iteration. Better would be something not depending on the garbage collector collecting the identifier-less stream objects left behind after running the constructors. I am not using threads either, should I?

I am still studying Java, so I am really sorry if I am incorrect on anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple generic `Swapable` class should allow you to swap between two objects.

```
class Swapable<T> {
    final T a;
    final T b;
    boolean useA = true;

    Swapable(T a, T b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    T get() {
        return useA ? a : b;
    }

    void swap() {
        useA = !useA;
    }
}
```

Create your two `RandomAccessFile`s and install them in a `Swapable`. Use the `get` method to get the current file. Use the `swap` method to switch between them.